# Ionic keyboard. Autocompletion flickers when typing in input field

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, materialize

The following happens on every single input field I have. Any idea what could be causing it or how could I debug it?

I use normal inputs such as follows:

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="correo" type="email" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="userEmail" name="userEmail">
            <label for="correo">Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="pass1" type="password" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="userPassword" name="userPassword">
            <label for="pass1">Contraseña</label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I'm also using materialize.css:
https://materializecss.com/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `autocomplete="OFF"` in input tag where you don't want a suggestion while typing. Use autocomplete in input tag like this

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="correo" type="email" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="userEmail" name="userEmail" autocomplete="OFF">
            <label for="correo">Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="pass1" type="password" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="userPassword" name="userPassword" autocomplete="OFF">
            <label for="pass1">Contraseña</label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I guess I'll resort to that as last resource. But I want to have them, I just don't want them to flicker like in the image. They appear for a millisecond and then disappear after every single keystroke, even when there are no suggestions.

Comment: Also, I've tried that and doesn't seem to work, I've read that disabling them it's rather challenging... Does that work for you?

Comment: Yeah, it works fine for me, but you can use this when you don't want suggestions and the main point of flickering of that suggestion box is maybe because of the CSS. You should inspect that area maybe that will help to know the problem in detail.

Comment: It doesn't work, are you using Ionic 4? It also doesn't work on the browser. https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8

Comment: The <ion-input> also flickers. I'll disable the css and check

Comment: This is how I did it

`<input [(ngModel)] = "mobileNumber" name="name" placeholder="Mobile Number" type="number" class="form-control" autocomplete="OFF">`

Comment: That solution depends on the browser, and it doesn't work with my setup (and probably with many other people, so it is not an universal solution unfortunately)

Comment: I've disabled all CSS and still same issue, so it has to be something related to ionic

Comment: If you are using materializecss then add `class="autocomplete"` in your input field. Like :

            `<input id="correo" type="email" class="validate autocomplete" [(ngModel)]="userEmail" name="userEmail">`

Comment: That doesn't change anything, still same effect. It flickers after each keystroke